# simulation of broken objectes in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody :)

Can we simulate broken objects ? for example if we have a revolute joint between two boxes. And something more solid and heavy fall over, will the joint be broken ?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7379/simulation-of-broken-objectes-in-gazebo/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you can [detach](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/3.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#aec25f3109f6768ea12c99854042efd3f) a joint when a given limit is reached (e.g. [force](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/3.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#ace2650b2f405eae19c817b7a80297ab2)).

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/1b4e0d9b54918850aee9e57af906d1471b3f19f6/plugins/BreakableJointPlugin.cc?at=default) is the source of an example plugin.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2014-11-05**:
thank you,I will try that out !